# MATLAB/Embedded Coder File Loading

Tags: matlab, load, matlab-coder

I generated code for loading a mat file as follows

```
data=coder.load('data.mat');
a=data.a;
b=data.b;
```

Because one of the variables, for example "a", is very big, it is defined as a big static const array in the main function with all values initialized there.

Is there any way I can make MATLAB Coder load data from a file in C Code instead of defining it as a variable in main function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact code that we should use based on Ryan's answer:

```
load('Data.mat')
fileID = fopen('Data.bin', 'w');
fwrite(fileID, Matrix1,'uint64');
fclose(fileID);


fileID=fopen('Data.bin');
Matrix2=fread(fileID,[256,256],'uint64');
fclose(fileID);
```

Matrix 2 is now the same as Matrix 1. The trick for writing and reading is to use the same precision based on the data type.

Answer (score 3):

The MATLAB `fread` function is supported for code generation. So you can `fwrite` the data to a file in MATLAB and then `fread` it in the generated code. This will do a runtime read and avoid the giant constant in the generated code.

Comment: Try to specify the precision argument to `fread` and `fwrite`. Say you have `int32` values, then use `'int32'` to write and `'*int32'` to read them as 32-bit integers. Just change the type name for your example.